# how to execute "ExecuteSqlRawAsync" in in-memory database

Tags: c#, xunit

I am creating unit test case using x-unit and in-memory database and i am trying to execute the below line of code

```
await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(lockSql, cancellationToken);
```

I am getting the below error :    Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.

How do i fix this and proceed with the test case?

Comment: You can use SQLite for testing. Or look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966101/how-to-unit-test-a-function-in-net-core-3-1-that-uses-executesqlrawasync-to-cal) question

Comment: The error is clear. The In-Memory database is essentially a dictionary, meant for simple tests,  not a full-featured database. The docs make it *very* clear it's limited, in fact in [Testing with the EF In-Memory Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) almost the entire visible page is covered by the warnings

Answer (score 1):

In-Memory Database has several issues that's why Microsoft prefers to use SQLite.
In-Memory Database does not allow to run raw queries.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database

Comment: It is not issues but features ;)